Check uniform convergence for $F_n(x)=\sin(x)^n$
So I have a small question, when I tried to prove the required; check point convergence and uniform convergence for $F_n(x)=\sin(x)^n$ for $A \in [0,\pi/2)$
I tried to apply the Supremum test but a question in me;
if $a \in [0,\pi/2)$ shouldn't the supremum of |(sinx)^n| be 1? Since I remember that the supremum of a series is its upper limit. Assuming so, the functions series doesn't converge (but I already know that it does...)
When I applied the M test, I figured: $\sin(x)\le\sin(a)=M$ => $|\sin(x)^n|\le\ |M^n|=0$ thus the functions series does converge
I'll be glad to receive a clarification to where my thought is wrong, thanks!

Are you trying to prove that the series converges or the sequence converges?

Am trying to prove the functions series uniformly converges
